# End a game if a button is not tapped - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, button

So in this game, i have a button pop up for a short amount of time. If the button disappears before the user clicks it, then they lose the game. How can i make it so to check if the button has appeared and they have not clicked it during its duration of appearance they lose the game. I already have all my necessary functions for when the game is lost. All i need help with is how to read if a user did not click a button during its time of appearance.

```
@IBAction func tapButton(_ sender: Any) {

if colorImage.image == UIImage(named: "\(self.currentColorNumber).png") {

// give the user a point
}
```

So i am able to give them a point if they tap the button. How do i end the game if they do not tap the button?

Comment: This would be *exceedingly* easy to do in SpriteKit. For this, I suggest using something like Timer alongside a callback.

Answer (score 0):

Wow hold on just a minute of algorithmization. Why dont you detect the user didn't tap the button on the button disappearance? If the user cliecked the button, the action happens, some class bool gets true and something happens... that's fine as it is. If the user didn't, you listen to the point the button disappears and handle the custom action there. I don't see anything hard about that.